# How to view Bitcoin Cash (BCC) on Trezor Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, trezor

I'm on beta-wallet.trezor.io and I've updated the Firmware to 1.5.1 and still can't see any Bitcoin Cash listed (BTC).  Perhaps I'm being impatient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCH (Bcash) as Trezor refer to it, is now available on https://beta-wallet.trezor.io after applying 1.5.1 firmware upgrade. Go to https://beta-wallet.trezor.io

You can also use tool to claim your BCC, read more [on this blog page](https://blog.trezor.io/claim-bcash-bitcoin-cash-bch-bcc-trezor-wallet-f0a810d5864a)

Answer (score 0):

Trezor is busy updating their software. There is no predetermined date that your BCC will become available. They have suggested to check the coin dropdown menu consistently on your web wallet where "Bitcoin cash" will appear automatically when ready.